# Why in drl cannot define member variable in anonymous class

Tags: drools

When use anonymous in drools, I found you cannot define member variables in it

```
rule "abstract test"
agenda-group "abstract test"
when
    eval(true)
then
    new AbstractFoo(){
        private final Object obj = new Object();
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            synchronized (obj){
                System.out.println("doSomethong");
            }
        }
    }.doSomething();
end
```

When compile the drl, it gets the below error

```
2017-04-17 22:14:01.590 ERROR [main] [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.java:250] - Unable to build KieBaseModel:kbase
Unable to determine the used declarations.
java.util.EmptyStackException : [Rule name='abstract test']
java.util.EmptyStackException
```

Why is so?

Comment: Did you import AbstractFoo?

Comment: Yeah I import it